# How to use the new floor value in your calculation php

Tags: php

I am facing the below issue with my php code.

```
$value = 28.835223;
$newValue = floor($value);
```

When I echo `$newValue`, it will show `28`.
But when I use `$newValue` for a new calculation, the value is `28.835223`.

How can I use the new floor value "28" in my calculations?

Comment: No it should not returned to its float value, must be there something wrong with your calculations, please share the full code related to this issue

Comment: Your code should work. Look at your code, you must have used `$value` instead of your `$newValue`.

Comment: Thank you Mohammad, actually floor works fine, it was a mistake within the calculation.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code

```
$value = 28.835223;
$newValue = (int) $value;
echo $newValue;
```